# Linq _ If one parameter is null then return empty or string

Tags: linq, null

I am trying to join some tables by Linq, code as below:

```
public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> ListAllPaging(string searchString, int page, int pageSize)
    {

        var model1 = from a in db.Invoices
                     join b in db.InvoiceTypes
                     on a.InvoiceTypeId equals b.InvoiceTypeId
                     join c in db.Invoices
                     on a.ReturnFromInvoiceId equals c.InvoiceId
                     join d in db.Activities
                     on a.ActivityId equals d.ActivityId
                     select new InvoiceViewModel()
                     {
                         InvoiceId = a.InvoiceId,
                         InvoiceType = b.Name,
                         InvoiceCode = a.InvoiceCode,
                         ReturnFromInvoice = c.InvoiceCode,
                         AmountOnPaper = a.AmountOnPaper,
                         PaidAmount = a.PaidAmount,
                         PaidTime = a.PaidTime,
                         Activity = d.Name,
                         IsLocked = a.IsLocked,
                         CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate,
                         CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy,
                         ModifiedDate = a.ModifiedDate,
                         ModifiedBy = a.ModifiedBy,
                         Status = a.Status
                     };

        IQueryable<InvoiceViewModel> model = model1;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            model = model.Where(x => x.InvoiceCode.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return model.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
    }
```

When **ReturnFromInvoiceId = null** I want **ReturnFromInvoice = ""** and when **ActivityId = null** I want **Activity = ""**. Try many ways but doesn't work. Pls help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just did it, follow instruction of [Perform left outer joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

```
public IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> ListAllPaging(string searchString, int page, int pageSize)
    {

        var model1 = from a in db.Invoices
                     join b in db.InvoiceTypes
                     on a.InvoiceTypeId equals b.InvoiceTypeId
                     join c in db.Invoices
                     on a.ReturnFromInvoiceId equals c.InvoiceId into gj1
                     from re1 in gj1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join d in db.Activities
                     on a.ActivityId equals d.ActivityId into gj2
                     from re2 in gj2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new InvoiceViewModel()
                     {
                         InvoiceId = a.InvoiceId,
                         InvoiceType = b.Name,
                         InvoiceCode = a.InvoiceCode,
                         ReturnFromInvoice = re1.InvoiceCode ?? String.Empty,
                         AmountOnPaper = a.AmountOnPaper,
                         PaidAmount = a.PaidAmount,
                         PaidTime = a.PaidTime,
                         Activity = re2.Name ?? String.Empty,
                         IsLocked = a.IsLocked,
                         CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate,
                         CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy,
                         ModifiedDate = a.ModifiedDate,
                         ModifiedBy = a.ModifiedBy,
                         Status = a.Status
                     };

        IQueryable<InvoiceViewModel> model = model1;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            model = model.Where(x => x.InvoiceCode.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return model.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
    }
```